# ANGULAR2: Detecting Change in static variable of a class

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

I am writing a dragDirective. Eements are dragged in dragZones. On mouse releases I do a hitTest against all availabe dragZones. I am maintaining a static boolean flag which ends up being false if all hittests return false. In such a situation I would like to resposition the element in the dragZone it originally belonged to. How do I check against this change in variable value?

```
    this._messageBus.listen("dragStart", (obj, event) => {
        DragZoneDirective.HITTEST = false;
    }); 
    this._messageBus.listen("dragStop", (obj, event) => {
        if (this.hitTest(event.x, event.y))
        {
            //clone object
            let clone: Object = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
            this.dragZoneElems.push(clone);
            DragZoneDirective.HITTEST = true;
        }

        let index = this.dragZoneElems.indexOf(obj);
        if (index > -1)
            this.dragZoneElems.splice(index, 1);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Angular binding that is checked by Angular change detection on static fields.

You could add a getter on a component that forwards to that static field, then a binding to that getter would be checked by Angulars change detection.

IMHO the preferred way is to use an `Observable` that emits an event on change. Interested code can subscribe and get notified about updates.